# Synchronizing of threading

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a fragment class that describes `RecyclerView`. It takes `array` for creating elements. The `array`  is forming by parsing `JSON`. When I use good internet connection everything is  OK, and I can see desirable list of items. But using low-speed connection my `UI` is empty.

I realize that there are  some problems  with  `threads`, but I haven't  enough knowledge  to  fix  my  problem.

Here is a code:

```
public class ListVideo extends Fragment {
private int loadLimit = 9;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
List<VideoData> videoList;
List<String> videoDataList;
JSONArray json_array_list_of_videos;
int counter = 0;
int offset;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listvideofragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    videoList = new ArrayList<>();
    videoDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    loadData(offset);
    createRecycleView();
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(
            linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int offset) {
            // do somthing...

            loadMoreData(offset);

        }

    });


}

private void loadMoreData(int offset) {

    loadLimit += 10;
    loadData(offset);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void loadData(final int offset) {
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://video.motti.be/api/video.getVideoList?offset=" +
                        offset
                        + "&limit=20")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful())
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                    }

                    String json_string_obj = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject url = new JSONObject(json_string_obj);
                    json_array_list_of_videos = url.getJSONArray("data");
                    System.out.println(json_array_list_of_videos.toString());
                    for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++) {
                        if (json_array_list_of_videos.get(y).toString().equals("A9knX0GXrg")) {
                            videoDataList.add("6kS9Tt1e47g");
                        } else {
                            videoDataList.add(json_array_list_of_videos.get(y).toString());
                            System.out.println("++++++" + json_array_list_of_videos.get(y).toString());
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = counter; i <= loadLimit; i++) {
                        if (videoDataList == null) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            VideoData next_queue_id = new VideoData(videoDataList.get(i));
                            videoList.add(next_queue_id);
                            counter++;

                        }
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public void createRecycleView() {

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(videoList, getContext());
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

I understand, that  I  get  `Response` later then `new adapter` creates.For the lack of knowledge, as I sad,  I  have no  idea how  to  make  `thread`  with  `onResponse` method  to  wait.

Hope that you won't  find this question as dull or stupid   and  will help  me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to notify the adapter after you modify its list (`videoList`).

Currently the `loadMoreData(int offset)` method doesn't guaranty that because the `loadData(offset);` method can return before the list is modified (the request is processed asynchronously).

What you could do is this:

Remove the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` statement from the `loadMoreData(int offset)` method and add it to the `onResponse(Response response)` method.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
    try {
        ...
        for (int i = counter; i <= loadLimit; i++) {
            if (videoDataList == null) {
                return;
            } else {
                VideoData next_queue_id = new VideoData(videoDataList.get(i));
                videoList.add(next_queue_id);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        ListVideo.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This approach can create other problems because the `videoList` can be modified by multiple threads at the same time. You need to find a way to synchronize the access to this list or use a thread safe list.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Titus ! Had some problem with `runOnUiThread`, so I used `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` and  it  worked out! Thank you again!